# Rating Bar inside ListView mixes list items

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, ratingbar

I have been trying to implement a **ListView**, which has **Rating Bar** inside. I have `onRatingChanged` listener and I want to change a **TextView** inside the item depending on the rating.

The problem is that, when I touch stars and update it, it updates another **TextView's** value.
My Adapter extends **CursorAdapter**. If I had `getView()` I guess I would solve it but I dont know how to deal with **CursorAdapter** since we are not using getView().

```
|------------------|
| TextView         | ---> TextView I want to update
| * * * * *        | ---> Rating Bar
|                  |
|__________________|
```

Comment: The code you would use would be the same as for a non Cursor based adapter, the only difference is that you'd be using the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

Comment: How can I solve it then, I am really confused now

Comment: In custom adapter, I was using tagging, but I dont know how to deal with tagging here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, when I touch stars and update it, it updates
>   another TextView's value. My Adapter extends CursorAdapter. If I had
>   getView() I guess I would solve it but I dont know how to deal with
>   CursorAdapter since we are not using getView().

Like I already said in my comment in the case of `Cursor` based adapter you would use the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods. Below is a small example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final int CURSOR_TEXT_COLUMN = 0;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(cursor.getString(CURSOR_TEXT_COLUMN));
        holder.progress
                .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                            float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                        // basic example on how you may update the
                        // TextView(you could use a tag etc).
                        // Keep in mind that if you scroll this row and come
                        // back the value will reset as you need to save the
                        // new rating in a more persistent way and update
                        // the progress
                        View rowView = (View) ratingBar.getParent();
                        TextView text = (TextView) rowView
                                .findViewById(R.id.the_text);
                        text.setText(String.valueOf(rating));
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent,
                false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.the_text);
        holder.progress = (RatingBar) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.the_progress);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
        return rowView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        RatingBar progress;
    }

}
```

Comment: I got it now. Thanks man! I haven't seen an example of it with holder, I thought it works different than Base Adapter now it makes sense. It works perfect.

Comment: I have another question, do you have how can I get position of the list item when user touch to rating bar?
Once they change the rating, I want to determine which row it is and move my cursor to this position

Comment: I got now! You already used position as tag. With one answer you responded my two questions! Thanks

Comment: @GokhanArik The position of the row can easily be retrieved with `cursor.getPosition()`. If you put this value as a tag for the `RatingBar`, then you could retrieve that in the listener and do what you want.

Comment: When we use bindView, it shouldn't mix the views right? Because it checks whether View is null or not. Mine is still mixing rating bars and checkboxes inside the listview. Can you help?

Comment: @GokhanArik `bindView()` will be called to bind the data every time a new row appears on the screen. If you're still mixing rows then check what you do, for example, if you change the background based on a condition then make sure you have an else clause to handle a recycled row not matching that condition. If you don't manage to do it then post your code somewhere so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Looks like the problem is position. When I print list to screen they are correct, but when I log position inside onRatingBarChangedListener, I am getting wrong position.

Comment: Where should I set position as tag? When I set inside bindview() automatically, it is setting the last position of cursor every time. It is not passing the position of rating bar which belongs to the item

Comment: @GokhanArik Again, please post the code you used for your adapter.

Comment: Sorry for late, I figured it out. I was missing saving CheckBox state to somewhere else and using else statements. I am keeping my checkbox state in an ArrayList and using else statements now, it works perfect.Thanks again